# Setting default options for hvplots

Tags: python, holoviews, hvplot

I would like to set default options for the plots generated by hvplots.

Normally in holoviews I would do this to set defaults for every plot:

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')
opts.defaults(opts.Curve( height=400, width=900 ,show_grid=True))
```

Now that I'm using hvplots the import has become the following for xarray based plotting

```
import xarray as xr
import hvplot.xarray
```

If I have an xarray dataset and I want to plot one of the dimensions then I use this

```
ds.myDims.hvplot()
```

However this gives a plot with a default width and no grid lines. To add this I need to specify the options with the plot.

```
ds.myDims.hvplot(height=400, width=900,grid=True)
```

Ideally I'd like to set the height, width, grid etc globally, like I can in holoviews, so I don't have to specify it for every plot.

Comment: Mind filing a feature request for this on the hvPlot repo? I don't think there is currently any nice API for this.

Comment: Submitted as [issue 231](https://github.com/pyviz/hvplot/issues/231).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:**

With **hvplot >= 0.5** you can now set default settings for your plots as follows:

```
from holoviews import opts

opts.defaults(
    opts.Scatter(
        width=700, height=300, 
        color='black', 
        active_tools=['box_zoom'],
))
```

**Alternative (older) solution:**

Define your default settings in a dictionary and unpack that dictionary everytime you create plot:

```
default_settings = {'height': 400, 'width': 900}

plot = ds.myDims.hvplot(**default_settings)

another_plot = ds.myDims.hvplot(**default_settings)
```